# WordPress Polylang display all pages on the blog

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I have a problem with polylang pro - it displays all pages as a blog - if the module is disabled it is ok.

I will add that I don't have a blog on wordpress - I don't have an assigned page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtJop.png)

disable module,
change theme;

Comment: Where does it show all pages? On the homepage?